# Static HTML, want to use ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that hosts a static HTML webpage with text and some images. I want to use ruby on rails to learn about it more.

I have a simple ror app. I went to `app/views/home.html.erb`, and pasted the HTML I have there. This is not the best approach.

1. Is there a better approach to port this Static HTML to ror?
2. Where do javascript files go in ror?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should checkout [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage), which is a gem for static pages.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have helpers in RoR ERB to help you with HTML, especially if you connect to a DB, for example from their [help](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Summary</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= book.title %></td>
    <td><%= book.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Show", book %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_book_path(book) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Remove", book, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to "New book", new_book_path %>
```

Everything between `<%= ....  %>` are RoR helpers, so it's really up to your application if RoR will help you with your static HTML or not (maybe since you say it's static, i.e. not dynamic at all, the best approach would just be to leave it as is.

2) Javascript files are placed under `app/assets`, and you should definitely read about the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)